# Java - Checking for duplicates in arrayList and stop user from adding an order to the array

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, duplicates

A GUI program that displays a label at the top with "Order not added -duplicate" when a duplicate order is attemped to be added by the user.

for the order in orderList to be considered duplicate all inputs in textfields (when the button is clicked) have to be the same.

I suppose that I have to use a for loop to check if the order is already in the arrayList but I'm not sure how, I'm pretty new to java.

Comment: (Image)https://media.cheggcdn.com/media/4d7/4d7bf585-d8a9-4164-8046-9fc6b86f92cf/phpIH8Ghu.png

Comment: A `Set` would be the best structure to prevent duplicates, but for Objects with multiple variables you have to compare you will need to [override the equals and hashcode methods](https://www.techiedelight.com/how-to-use-equal-objects-as-key-hashmap-hashset-java/) to make it work in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an array you should be using a [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) which is a collection specifically designed to prevent duplicates:

> A Set is a Collection that cannot contain duplicate elements. It models the mathematical set abstraction. The Set interface contains only methods inherited from Collection and adds the restriction that duplicate elements are prohibited. Set also adds a stronger contract on the behavior of the equals and hashCode operations, allowing Set instances to be compared meaningfully even if their implementation types differ. Two Set instances are equal if they contain the same elements.

Since you are new to Java language take a step back and first learn about basic collections provided by the standard library: [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html), [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Once you understand this abstractions and their implementation variants you will be able to solve a lot of common day-to-day problems.

Answer (score 0):

While a `Set` would be good in a real world scenario, this appears to be a homework assignment with arbitrary limitations so let's see how it can be done using an `ArrayList`.

First thing I would recommend doing is overriding your `.equals()` method on your `Order` object to properly compare field values. Something like...

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  //Same reference so same object in every sense of the word
  if(obj == this)
    return true;
  //Not instanced nor the same class so clearly not equal
  if(obj == null || obj.getClass() != getClass())
    return false;

  //Cast it to the same object type
  Order o = (Order) obj;
  //Start comparing every variable, will return false if any of them don't match
  //Be sure to use the equals operation for any variable objects such as String
  return this.name.equals(o.name) && this.value == o.value && this.someVar == o.someVar; //ect...
}
```

Then you just need to take your fields and turn it into a object like normal...

```
Order order = new Order(field1.getText(), field2.getText(), field3.getText()); //ect...
```

And run it in a compare against the existing values. I recommend making a separate method for this...

```
public static boolean orderExists(Order order) {
  for(Order otherOrder : orderArrayList) {
    if(order.equals(otherOrder))
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

From there, the `orderExists()` method will tell you if it's already in there and you can implement your code for displaying the error. Hope this helps you get set up enough to handle the rest on your own alright!

Comment: How would it be if I use a for loop to just check if the inputs in the textfield are duplicate for instance I got something like.                                                                           For (int i=0 ; i<= orderList.length ; i++)  {                    
   String name = nameTxt.getText()                                             
    int Qty = Integer.parseInt(QtyTxt.getText());                     where do I go from here ?

Comment: @IndiraFragaAlfonso I would recommend moving those assignments outside the loop since there's no need to grab the values from the textfields over and over. You will also want a boolean flag such as `boolean matched = false;` outside the loop. Inside the loop do something like `if(orderList[i].name.equals(name) && orderList[i].qty == qty){ matched = true; break; }` to break out of the loop as soon as it finds a match. If no match is found then `matched` will remain false.

Comment: @IndiraFragaAlfonso Also, don't do `i <= orderList.length;` inside your loop header. That will cause an exception since length is 1 greater than the largest index position. Do `i < orderList.length;` instead.